# Why isn't the partial derivative of a coordinate patch a vector field?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Let $D$ be an open set of $R^2$ and M a surface in $R^3$.

Let $\mathbf{x(u,v)}: D \rightarrow M $ be a coordinate patch in M.

Let $\mathbf{x}_u, \mathbf{x}_v$ be partial derivatives of the patch.

Define $N(u,v):=\mathbf{x}_u(u,v) \times \mathbf{x}_v(u,v)$.

The book I am learning says that $\mathbf{x}_u, \mathbf{x}_v$ and $N$ are not vector fields on 
$\mathbf{x}(D)$. They are only vector valued functions on $D$.

Why isn't $\mathbf{x}_u$ a vector field on $\mathbf{x}(D)$?

Comment: Which book are you reading? My take is that in your situation they are also vector fields on the surface since to each point they assign a tangent vector.

Comment: Elementary differential geometry by O'Neill. Section 5.4

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a typo. On page 211 it should propably read "that in this context, $U$, **un**like $x_{u}$ and ..."

Well either that, or he has a strange definition of vector field in this book.